# Get running project id from custom prediction classes

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm looking the way to get a Project ID of GCP, running on [AI Platform Custom Prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines)

My project has 3 project that has **dev, stage and prod**, each project has to access unique URL from inside of custom prediction. And custom prediction codes are controlled by a single project.

I've tried `gcloud` command running with `subprocess` but It didn't work for me.

Comment: does this work inside your custom prediction Python code? ```import os; PROJECT_ID=os.environ.get('PROJECT_ID')```

Comment: Yes, I`ve just checked that code, but it returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that project number has a relationship with project id and `os.environ.get("consumer_project_number")`can get a value of project number in Custom Prediction.

This is my final code to get Project ID.

```py
if consumer_project_number == "hoge_1":
    return "prd_ID"
elif consumer_project_number == "hoge_2":
    return "stg_ID"
elif consumer_project_number == "hoge_3":
    return "dev_ID"
else:
    raise ValueError("None consumer_project_number detected.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, where I needed the project name, went with following code

```
PROJECT_ID = ast.literal_eval(os.getenv('create_version_request')).get('parent').split('/', 2)[1]
print(f'PROJECT_ID={PROJECT_ID}', flush=True)
```